# why elasticsearch cluster's heap usage so mutch?

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-memory

why my elasticsearch cluster's heap usage so mutch. while there just a littile request?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses memory for few different purposes, all in order to provide faster search times and high indexing throughput.

The heap usage you pasted doesn't look high. Elasticsearch runs its Java process in the JVM. The JVM manages the heap and clears memory through garbage collection. looking at heap usage graph you will usually see the usage increasing constantly, and then sudden drops - which happen when the GC (Garbage collector) releases the unused memory.

Do you have a specific issue with memory? it looks ok - ranging between 40%-70% is perfectly normal.